# Probability to starve

Tags: probability

First of all, I'm sorry if I'll use some game related terms, but that's where the question that bugged me for the last week came from.

Let's say, we have a mana pool of size $M$, and we can cast a spell that costs $n$, with $n < M$. The spell has a  probability $p$ to give us $kM$ mana, where both $p$ and $k$ are fixed constants in the interval $[0,1]$.

What is the probability to get mana starved, that means, to end up without enough mana to cast any more instances of our spell after $t$ casts?

edit : as a first ( and simpler ) case, we can assume $M = qn$ with $q \in N , q > 1$ and $kM = pn , p < q$ .

Comment: Shall we assume that this does not take into account regeneration per time unit?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to keep things "simple", so I ignored the mana regeneration ... and since usually that is a small amount compared to N,this shouldn't introduce too much bias

Comment: This is similar to the idea of 'first return' in random walks.

Comment: Does "a mana pool of size $M$" mean that you can never have more than $M$ mana, or just that you initally have $M$ mana? And are any of these quantities restricted to integers?

Comment: $M$ is both the maximum mana you can have, and his starting value. I guess, for simplicity, we could assume both $M$ and $n$ as integers; for a starting case, we could also assume that $M = qn$ with $q$ integer greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

You get starved after $q$ casts if you have had at most $w$ successes and $(q+1)n \gt M+wkM$.  The probability of $w$ or less successes is $\sum_{j=0}^w {q \choose j}p^j(1-p)^{(w-j)}$.  This does not guarantee you haven't already starved.

Answer (score 1):

I can give a partial answer for the case $M,n,kM\in\mathbb{N}$. In this case, you can model your situation as a discrete Markov-chain on $\{0,\dots,M\}$. The $M+1\times M+1$ transition matrix $P$ is described by

$$P_{ij}=\cases{1 &\text{ if $i=j<n$}\\ 1-p &\text{ if $i\geq n, j=i-n$}\\ p & \text{if $i\geq , j=i+kM$}\\ p & \text{if $\geq (1-k)M, j=M$}\\0&\text{ otherwise.}}$$

As an example, for $n=1, kM=2, M=4$ this looks like

$$P = \left(\matrix{1&0&0&0&0\\1-p&0&0&p&0\\0&1-p&0&0&p\\0&0&1-p&0&p\\0&0&0&1-p&p}\right)$$

The probability $q$ you are interested in is

$$q = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}P^{t}_{Mi}$$

I don't see a nice short form for this expression, but it can surely be evaluated by a CAS.